# What does "nine while nine" mean?

Tags: meaning

In "Nine While Nine" by The Sisters of Mercy there is this line:

> Nine while nine and I'm waiting for the train...

What does "nine while nine" actually mean? I've never encountered anything similar in English apart from "nine to five" maybe. Perhaps these are related somehow?

Comment: [***Nine while nine** is a northern phrase meaning **from X til Y**, in this case **9 am til 9pm***](https://www.vamp.org/Gothic/Text/sisters-faq.html) But I never heard it before (I'm *Southern* UK). I think it might have been used for what we normally call a ***seven-eleven*** (a local shop that opens early and closes late).

Comment: From [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=lSgiAAAAMAAJ&q=%22nine+while+five%22&dq=%22nine+while+five%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUt725lNDNAhULGx4KHeWVCx4Q6AEIQDAH), 1986, about Sheffield. *At Doncaster's there had been a foreman on every shift but at Niagara all the gaffers just worked nine while five. After five there was no one in charge. I used to work on the afternoon shift from two while ten.* So it's not new.

Comment: So from the comments by FungleFingers and Peter Shor (sorry, apparently I can't "@" you both), it sounds like the line means the speaker has had a very long day at work (9 am to 9 pm...or worse, 9 pm to 9 am) and is now waiting for the train to at last go home.

Comment: More common is the 6-6 twelve hour shift pattern known in industrial south Yorkshire "six while six". It seems that the [Sisters of Mercy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sisters_of_Mercy) were from Leeds originality so the idea that "nine while nine" means a twelve-hour stint at work sounds very likely. I'd need to see or hear the rest of the lyrics to know quite what it means.

Answer (score 5):

The sense is recognised by the OED, as a "chiefly Northern" one.

> b. as prep. Up to (a time), up to the time of; till, until. Now
> dialect (chiefly northern).

It actually has examples dating from 1455. More recent ones are:

> 1721   Coll. Polit. Lett. London Jrnl. 1720 14   Tho' he sweat and
> scrub while Doomsday. 1722   Mason's Acct. in C. Wordsworth Rutland
> Words (1891) 39   I was 2 dayes; And my Son was 2 days. And the third
> day wile three a Clock. 1854   A. E. Baker Gloss. Northamptonshire
> Words II. 393   It wants a quarter while nine o'clock.

Answer (score 2):

It’s whats said in some parts of Yorkshire when referring to time. Instead of saying *to* they say *while*, so it means 9am to 9pm.

Answer (score 1):

<Doncaster lad here: born late '60s>
"xxx while xxx", referring to time, was indeed not uncommon as a phrase.

Comment: Hi, it's good to have your input. This answer would benefit from a reference or citation to support your comments.  Please take the [tour] and see the [FAQ], and welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 0):

"While" just means "until", as in "wait while I close the door", "wait while they score before you start booing" etc. It's west/south Yorkshire mostly.

"Nine while nine" means "Nine til nine", like "nine while five" in the example above means "nine til five"